# How to request existing files from a form in django

Tags: python, django, forms, profile

i'm trying to add a feature for users to update thier profile, but i want to be able to get thier existing informations so they don't have to fill all the form again. I have tried `request.POST`  on the form but it doesn't work, it does not update the form with the existing user informations.

views.py

```
def profile_update(request):
    info = Announcements.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Acount Updated Successfully!')
            return redirect('userauths:profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
    
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'info': info,
        'categories': categories
    }

    return render(request, 'userauths/profile_update.html', context)





# profile update function
def profile_update(request):
    info = Announcements.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Acount Updated Successfully!')
            return redirect('userauths:profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
    
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'info': info,
        'categories': categories
    }

    return render(request, 'userauths/profile_update.html', context)
```

Comment: Update your question with urls.py and the html from where you are calling the view

Comment: @Ahtisham okay i've dont that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the model instance associated with your form with `{{form.instance}}`.

```
{{p_form.instance.first_name}}
```

EDIT:

Here while saving the ProfileUpdateForm you are not handling the field user so you can handle user in your profile form like this.

```
 if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
     user = u_form.save()        
     profile = p_form.save(commit=False)
     profile.user = user
     profile.save()
```

Comment: when i use {{p_form.instance.first_name}} it just show the instance of the name that's already there but i can't update it again to a new one

Comment: Can you share your forms too ? Is there any errors ?

Comment: there are no errors

Comment: You can display your form errors with `{{ form.errors}}` in your template.